# How to get the response(json format) in console while hitting the url

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This is my code..where i have to integrate that part and how to proceed...

```js
function  validate() {

  var  un = document.loginscreen.uname.value;

  var  pw = document.loginscreen.psw.value;

  var  username =  "John_Smith";

  var  password =  "syntel123$";

  if  ((un == username) && (pw == password)) {

    window.location =  "file:///C:/Users/KS5034674/Desktop/Gagile/WebContent/homescreen.html";

    return  true;

  } else  {

    console.log("login Failed");

  }

}
```

```css
form {
  width: 100%;
  border: 0px solid #f1f1f1;
}

.container {
  padding: 16px;
  text-align: center;
}

input[type=text],
input[type=password] {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40%;
  padding: 15px 10px 6px 9px;
  margin-: 80px;
  display: inline-tablecolumngroup;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#input_container {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0 0 0 0px;
  margin: 0 20px;
  direction: ltr;
  width: 80%;
}

#input {
  height: 40px;
  margin: 0;
  width: 80%;
  text-align: center;
}

#input_img {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 50px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}

#input_container1 {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0 0 0 0px;
  margin: 0 20px;
  direction: ltr;
  width: 80%;
}

#input1 {
  height: 40px;
  margin: 0;
  width: 80%;
  text-align: center;
}

#input_img1 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 50px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}

button {
  background-color: #0052A6;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 70%;
  height: 40px;
}

.imgcontainer {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 24px 0 12px 0;
}

img.syntel {
  width: 40%;
  border-radius: 0%;
}

img.agileimg {
  width: 30%;
  border-radius: 40%;
}

img.abc {
  padding: 0 0px 0px 0px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}

span.psw {
  float: right;
  padding-top: 16px;
}


/* Change styles for span and cancel button on extra small screens */

@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  span.psw {
    display: block;
    float: none;
  }
  .cancelbtn {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">

    <meta name="viewport"  content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

      <link rel="stylesheet"  href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

          <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



            <body>

              <form name="loginscreen"  onsubmit="return validate()" action="file:///C:/Users/KS5034674/Desktop/Gagile/WebContent/homescreen.html"  method="post"  >

                <div class="imgcontainer">

                  <br> <br><br>
                  <img src=" C:\Users\KS5034674\Downloads\Gagile\project images\syntel.png"  alt="syntel"  class="syntel">

                    <br><br><br> <br>
                    <img src=" C:\Users\KS5034674\Downloads\Gagile\project images\agileimg.png"  alt="agileimg"  class="agileimg">

                      </div>

                      <br><br><br>

                      <div id="placeholder"  align="center"></div>

                        <div class="container">

                          <div id="input_container">

                            <input type="text"  id="input"  placeholder="Username"  name="uname"  required style="border-radius:7px;">

                              <img src=" C:\Users\KS5034674\Downloads\Gagile\project images\username.png"  id="input_img">

                                </div><br><br><br>

                                <div id="input_container1">

                                  <input type="password"  id="input1"  placeholder="Password"  name="psw"  required style="border-radius:7px;">

                                    <img src=" C:\Users\KS5034674\Downloads\Gagile\project images\password.png"  id="input_img1">

                                      </div>

                                      </div>

                                      <br><br>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
                                      <img src=" C:\Users\KS5034674\Downloads\Gagile\project images\check.png"  class="abc">&nbsp&nbsp<small>Remember me</small>

                                        <br><br><br>
                                        <div class="container">

                                          <button type="submit"  >Login</button><br><br><br><br><br><br>


</head>

</form>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please explain more about your problem

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Please see this post https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  on how to ask a question. Please simplify your code to the bare minimal to what you require and be very clear on what you expect the community to help you with.

Comment: @AmirMohsen actually this is a login screen UI code. Now i have to consume an api by hitting an url to gt the response

Answer (score 0):

Hi please use this code this is get the data in json after you can hit the url 
this is jsonv.json file and after that validate() function

```
{"user_name":"test","password":"testing"}

function  validate() {
 var jsdata;
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url:"jsonv.json", 
        dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify({
            user_name: $("#input").val(), 
            password: $("#input1").val()
        }),
        success: function(response) {
            jsdata=response;
            var  un = document.loginscreen.uname.value;

            var  pw = document.loginscreen.psw.value; 

            if  ((un == jsdata.user_name) && (pw == jsdata.password)) {
            alert(jsdata.user_name+'//'+jsdata.password);
            //window.location =  "file:///C:/Users/KS5034674/Desktop/Gagile/WebContent/homescreen.html";

             return  true;

            } else  {

              console.log("login Failed");

            }
        },
        error: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
}); 
}
```

Comment: Http://172.25.183.183:8080/JIRAservice/rest/login/...where i have to add this url in my code? I need to hit this url to gt response

Comment: Its not moving to next page if its successfully logged in

Answer (score 0):

if you have store the data in any url then you can post the ajax url:'' and if you want to login success after open new page same tab then use _self

```
function  validate() {
 var jsdata;
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:"http://172.25.183.183:8080/JIRAservice/rest/login/", 
        dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify({
            user_name: $("#input").val(), 
            password: $("#input1").val()
        }),
        success: function(response) {
            jsdata=response;
            var  un = document.loginscreen.uname.value;

            var  pw = document.loginscreen.psw.value; 

            if  ((un == jsdata.user_name) && (pw == jsdata.password)) {
                var myWindow = window.open("file:///C:/Users/KS5034674/Desktop/Gagile/WebContent/homescreen.html", "_self");
             return  true;

            } else  {

              console.log("login Failed");

            }
        },
        error: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
}); 
}
```